# Derivative of moment generating function

Tags: calculus, probability, derivatives, moment-generating-functions

If the moment generating function of $X$ exists, i.e., $$M_X(t)=E[e^{tX}],$$ then the derivative with respect to $t$ is usually taken as $$\frac{dM_X(t)}{dt}=E[Xe^{tX}].$$ Usually, if we want to change the order of derivative and calculus, there are some conditions need to verified. Why the derivative goes inside for the moment generating function?

Comment: See the answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1620326

Answer (score 8):

Lame, but what I could find:

(1) "If a moment generating function exists, then $m(t)$ is continuously differentiable in some neighborhood of the origin." Mood, Graybill, Boes (1974) *An Intro. to the Theory of Statistics,* 3e, p78.

If you make differentiability  part of the *definition* of MGF, then there is nothing to prove.

(2) Similarly, shortly after the definition and informal proofs of properties of MGFs, "If the MGF of $X$ exists, then $E(X^r) = M_X^{(r)}(0)$ for all $r = 1,2, \dots$ and $M_X(t) = 1 + \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{E(X^r)t^r}{r!}.$" Bain, Englehardt (1992): *Intro. to Probability and Mathematical Statistics,* 2e, p79.

(3) However, many other authors use phrases such as "assuming differentiation is allowed [inside the expectation]..." (always without elaboration in sources I found).

Because characteristic functions (which exist for all distributions) are used in more formal and advanced texts, I'm wondering if there are slightly different definitions of MGFs in various mid-level texts.

The relevant [*Wikipedia article*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function) (as of 12 Sept '17) seems
skeletal--and unhelpful on this issue.

Answer (score 5):

This is a general result for power series. For the power series 
$$
g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n (x-b)^n
$$
with radius of convergence $R>0$, then for any $x \in (b-R, b+R)$, the derivative of $g$ exists and is given by
$$
g'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n a_n (x-b)^{n-1}.
$$
You can use this fact along with the result that for any real valued random variable $X$ with mgf $m_X(t)$, $|t|< \delta$. Then $\mathbb{E}X^n$ exists and is finite for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and 
$$
m_X(t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^n \mathbb{E} X^n}{n!}, \quad |t| < \delta. 
$$
This is Theorem 4.8 in the text [Elements of Distribution Theory by Severini](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1107630738)